# Check for Elements Not Shared by Two List [PYTHON 2.7]

Tags: python, logical-operators

I have two arrays I need to compare to remove certain elements. My problem is that comparing array elements to make sure they are the same is easy, but how do I ensure that two elements are not the same?

```
for e in is_And_Should_Be: #delete who shouldn't be here
    for l in USERS:
        if (is_And_Should_Be[e] == USERS[l]):
            current = USERS[l]
            proc = Popen(['deluser', current],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
            if proc.returncode == 0:
                print "%s deleted" % current
```

If I had steve, dan, and john who should be there and dan, steve, and satan who were already there, how would I make sure only satan was deleted, because my solution (or rather dilemma) would have dan deleted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to use Python's [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and find the difference:

```
is_and_should_be = ['Steve', 'Dan', 'John']
users = ['Steve', 'Dan', 'Satan']
deletables = set(users).difference(set(is_and_should_be))
for user_to_delete in deletables:
    users.remove(user_to_delete)
```

In the above, I'm assuming you are using Python [lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), instead of [arrays](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#module-array).

Comment: I am using arrays although I can switch to lists if that is the only way, but I have no former experience working with them so that would be fairly inconvenient.

Comment: @demcooltricks: Python lists can be used much like arrays and are usually used in instead of arrays. If your initializations look like the above sample code, then you're using lists. [Arrays](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) require a module import and are meant for numeric processing. In over 10 years of Python programming I have almost never used them. While working on this answer, I couldn't find a way to create an array of strings. Thus, I suspect you're really using lists without realizing it. It can be a bit confusing when coming from another language.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following (assuming this is the example list of USERS you mentioned:

```
USERS = ["Steve", "Dan", "John", "Dan", "Steve", "Satan"]
while "Satan" in USERS:
    USERS.remove("Satan")
print USERS
['Steve', 'Dan', 'John', 'Dan', 'Steve']
```

Answer (score 0):

`master_list = ["Steve", "Dan", "John", "Satan"]`

`desired_list = ["Steve", "Dan", "John"]`

`unwanted_user = [name for name in master_list if not name in desired_list]`

`print(unwanted_user)`

['Satan']

`master_list.remove(unwanted_user[0])`

`print(master_list)`

['Steve', 'Dan', 'John']